# PDF Inline Image XObject Source Unknown error

Tags: image, pdf, inline-images, syntax-object

Getting error in PDF-Online.com that 'The name **Im1** of a xobject resource is unknown.' in the following PDF below. In Object 41 I establish the XObject 6 with the Image Name of Im1. When I view this file in Adobe it displays an error message box that states there is an error in the file. I can get past this error message and adobe displays the PDF file without rendering the Image.

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj<< /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R>>endobj
2 0 obj<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0>>endobj
3 0 obj<< /Type /Pages /Kids [ 4 0 R] /Count 1>>endobj
4 0 obj<< /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /MediaBox [ 0 0 792 612 ] /Contents 5 0 R /Resources << /**ProcSet 41 0 R** /Font << /F1 7 0 R /F2 8 0 R /F3 9 0 R /F4 10 0 R /F5 11 0 R /F6 12 0 R /F7 13 0 R /F8 14 0 R /F9 15 0 R /F10 16 0 R /F11 17 0 R /F12 18 0 R /F13 19 0 R /F14 20 0 R /F15 21 0 R /F16 23 0 R /F17 25 0 R /F18 27 0 R /F19 29 0 R /F20 31 0 R /F21 33 0 R /F22 35 0 R /F23 37 0 R /F24 39 0 R>>>>>>endobj
5 0 obj<< /Length 17136 >>
stream
[ ] 0 d 1 w 1.0 1.0 1.0 RG 0.9 0.9 0.91 rg 25 77.04 m 514.68 77.04 l 519.68 77.04 519.68 77.04 519.68 82.04 c 519.68 547.024 l 519.68 552.024 519.68 552.024 514.68 552.024 c 25 552.024 l 20 552.024 20 552.024 20 547.024 c 20 82.04 l 20 77.04 20 77.04 25 77.04 c b
[ ] 0 d 1 w 1.0 1.0 1.0 RG 1.0 1.0 1.0 rg 41.904 487.008 m 407.952 487.008 l 409.896 487.008 409.896 487.008 409.896 488.952 c 409.896 487.008 l 409.896 488.952 409.896 488.952 407.952 488.952 c 41.904 488.952 l 39.96 488.952 39.96 488.952 39.96 487.008 c 39.96 488.952 l 39.96 487.008 39.96 487.008 41.904 487.008 c b
[ ] 0 d 1 w 1.0 1.0 1.0 RG 0.9 0.9 0.91 rg 552.9312 522 m 746.3808 522 l 749.376 522 749.376 522 749.376 524.9952 c 749.376 522 l 749.376 524.9952 749.376 524.9952 746.3808 524.9952 c 552.9312 524.9952 l 549.936 524.9952 549.936 524.9952 549.936 522 c 549.936 524.9952 l 549.936 522 549.936 522 552.9312 522 c b
[ ] 0 d 1 w 1.0 1.0 1.0 RG 0.9 0.9 0.91 rg 552.9312 442.008 m 746.3808 442.008 l 749.376 442.008 749.376 442.008 749.376 445.0032 c 749.376 442.008 l 749.376 445.0032 749.376 445.0032 746.3808 445.0032 c 552.9312 445.0032 l 549.936 445.0032 549.936 445.0032 549.936 442.008 c 549.936 445.0032 l 549.936 442.008 549.936 442.008 552.9312 442.008 c b
[ ] 0 d 1 w 1.0 1.0 1.0 RG 0.95 1.0 1.0 rg 44.96 202.032 m 494.896 202.032 l 499.896 202.032 499.896 202.032 499.896 207.032 c 499.896 337 l 499.896 342 499.896 342 494.896 342 c 44.96 342 l 39.96 342 39.96 342 39.96 337 c 39.96 207.032 l 39.96 202.032 39.96 202.032 44.96 202.032 c b
[ ] 0 d 1 w 1.0 1.0 1.0 RG 1.0 1.0 1.0 rg 44.96 97.0056 m 494.896 97.0056 l 499.896 97.0056 499.896 97.0056 499.896 102.0056 c 499.896 167.0008 l 499.896 172.0008 499.896 172.0008 494.896 172.0008 c 44.96 172.0008 l 39.96 172.0008 39.96 172.0008 39.96 167.0008 c 39.96 102.0056 l 39.96 97.0056 39.96 97.0056 44.96 97.0056 c b
q 100 0 0 100 65 326 cm /Im1 Do Q 
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 570 492 Td(Account Name:) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 12 Tf 570 480 Td(LARRY MCGUIRE) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 570 462 Td(Account Number:) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 12 Tf 570 450 Td(1010000026) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.93 0.15 0.25 rg 0.93 0.15 0.25 RG BT /F14 12 Tf 70 147 Td(v) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 12 Tf 80 147 Td(An important note from SunGard) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 9 Tf 70 127 Td(BROKER GRAPHICAL STATEMENT ) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0 0.32 0.58 rg 0 0.32 0.58 RG BT /F5 14 Tf 60 462 Td(Summary of your investments) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F7 10 Tf 260 457 Td(As of Last Period) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F7 10 Tf 445 135 Td(This Period) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 60 439 Td(CASH EQUIVALENTS                   ) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 180 153 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 185.4 153 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 190.8 153 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 196.2 153 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 201.6 153 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 207 153 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 212.4 153 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 217.8 153 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 223.2 153 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 228.6 153 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 234 153 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 239.4 153 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 244.8 153 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 250.2 153 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 255.6 153 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 261 153 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 266.4 153 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 271.8 153 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 277.2 153 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 282.6 153 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 288 153 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 293.4 153 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 298.8 153 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 304.2 153 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 309.6 153 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 315 153 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 320.4 153 Td(.) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 325.8 153 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 331.2 153 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 336.6 153 Td(-) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 342 153 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 347.4 153 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 352.8 153 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 358.2 153 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 363.6 153 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 369 153 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 374.4 153 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 379.8 153 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 385.2 153 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 390.6 153 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 396 153 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 401.4 153 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 406.8 153 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 412.2 153 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 417.6 153 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 423 153 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 428.4 153 Td(5) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 433.8 153 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 439.2 153 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 444.6 153 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 450 153 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 455.4 153 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 460.8 153 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 466.2 153 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 471.6 153 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 477 153 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 482.4 153 Td(.) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 487.8 153 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 493.2 153 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 498.6 153 Td(-) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
[1 2] 0 d 1 w 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG 1.0 1.0 1.0 rg .5 w 39.96 445.5 m 499.9536 445.5 l S 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG 1.0 1.0 1.0 rg
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 60 421 Td(Priced Investments) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 75 403 Td(  EQUITIES                         ) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F9 10 Tf 180 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 185.4 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 190.8 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 196.2 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 201.6 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 207 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 212.4 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 217.8 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 223.2 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 228.6 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 234 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 239.4 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 244.8 189 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 250.2 189 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 255.6 189 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 261 189 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 266.4 189 Td(5) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 271.8 189 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 277.2 189 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 282.6 189 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 288 189 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 293.4 189 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 298.8 189 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 304.2 189 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 309.6 189 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 315 189 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 320.4 189 Td(.) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 325.8 189 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 331.2 189 Td(5) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 336.6 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 342 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 347.4 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 352.8 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 358.2 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 363.6 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 369 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 374.4 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 379.8 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 385.2 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 390.6 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 396 189 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 401.4 189 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 406.8 189 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 412.2 189 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 417.6 189 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 423 189 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 428.4 189 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 433.8 189 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 439.2 189 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 444.6 189 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 450 189 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 455.4 189 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 460.8 189 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 466.2 189 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 471.6 189 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 477 189 Td(.) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 482.4 189 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F9 10 Tf 487.8 189 Td(1) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 20 403 Td() Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 75 180 Td(  FIXED                            ) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 180 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 185.4 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 190.8 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 196.2 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 201.6 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 207 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 212.4 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 217.8 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 223.2 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 228.6 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 234 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 239.4 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 244.8 412 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 250.2 412 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 255.6 412 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 261 412 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 266.4 412 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 271.8 412 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 277.2 412 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 282.6 412 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 288 412 Td(5) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 293.4 412 Td(5) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 298.8 412 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 304.2 412 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 309.6 412 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 315 412 Td(5) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 320.4 412 Td(.) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 325.8 412 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 331.2 412 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 336.6 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 342 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 347.4 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 352.8 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 358.2 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 363.6 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 369 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 374.4 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 379.8 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 385.2 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 390.6 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 396 412 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 401.4 412 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 406.8 412 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 412.2 412 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 417.6 412 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 423 412 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 428.4 412 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 433.8 412 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 439.2 412 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 444.6 412 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 450 412 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 455.4 412 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 460.8 412 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 466.2 412 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 471.6 412 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 477 412 Td(.) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 482.4 412 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 487.8 412 Td(1) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 75 171 Td(  OTHER ASSETS                     ) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 180 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 185.4 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 190.8 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 196.2 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 201.6 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 207 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 212.4 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 217.8 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 223.2 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 228.6 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 234 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 239.4 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 244.8 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 250.2 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 255.6 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 261 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 266.4 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 271.8 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 277.2 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 282.6 421 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 288 421 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 293.4 421 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 298.8 421 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 304.2 421 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 309.6 421 Td(5) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 315 421 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 320.4 421 Td(.) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 325.8 421 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 331.2 421 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 336.6 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 342 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 347.4 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 352.8 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 358.2 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 363.6 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 369 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 374.4 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 379.8 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 385.2 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 390.6 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 396 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 401.4 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 406.8 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 412.2 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 417.6 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 423 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 428.4 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 433.8 421 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 439.2 421 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 444.6 421 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 450 421 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 455.4 421 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 460.8 421 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 466.2 421 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 471.6 421 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 477 421 Td(.) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 482.4 421 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 487.8 421 Td(0) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F7 10 Tf 60 367 Td(Sub-total) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
[1 2] 0 d 1 w 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG 1.0 1.0 1.0 rg .5 w 39.96 231.5 m 499.9536 231.5 l S 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG 1.0 1.0 1.0 rg
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 180 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 185.4 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 190.8 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 196.2 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 201.6 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 207 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 212.4 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 217.8 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 223.2 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 228.6 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 234 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 239.4 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 244.8 225 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 250.2 225 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 255.6 225 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 261 225 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 266.4 225 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 271.8 225 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 277.2 225 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 282.6 225 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 288 225 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 293.4 225 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 298.8 225 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 304.2 225 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 309.6 225 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 315 225 Td(1) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 320.4 225 Td(.) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 325.8 225 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 331.2 225 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 336.6 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 342 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 347.4 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 352.8 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 358.2 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 363.6 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 369 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 374.4 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 379.8 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 385.2 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 390.6 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 396 225 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 401.4 225 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 406.8 225 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 412.2 225 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 417.6 225 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 423 225 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 428.4 225 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 433.8 225 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 439.2 225 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 444.6 225 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 450 225 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 455.4 225 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 460.8 225 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 466.2 225 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 471.6 225 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 477 225 Td(.) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 482.4 225 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 487.8 225 Td(2) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F7 10 Tf 60 349 Td(Total Portfolio) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
[1 2] 0 d 1 w 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG 1.0 1.0 1.0 rg .5 w 39.96 249.5 m 499.9536 249.5 l S 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG 1.0 1.0 1.0 rg
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 180 243 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 185.4 243 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 190.8 243 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 196.2 243 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 201.6 243 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 207 243 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 212.4 243 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 217.8 243 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 223.2 243 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 228.6 243 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 234 243 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 239.4 243 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 244.8 243 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 250.2 243 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 255.6 243 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 261 243 Td(5) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 266.4 243 Td(5) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 271.8 243 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 277.2 243 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 282.6 243 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 288 243 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 293.4 243 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 298.8 243 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 304.2 243 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 309.6 243 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 315 243 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 320.4 243 Td(.) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 325.8 243 Td(0) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 331.2 243 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 336.6 243 Td(-) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 342 243 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 347.4 243 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 352.8 243 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 358.2 243 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 363.6 243 Td( ) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 369 243 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 374.4 243 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 379.8 243 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 385.2 243 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 390.6 243 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 396 243 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 401.4 243 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 406.8 243 Td(3) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 412.2 243 Td(9) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 417.6 243 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 423 243 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 428.4 243 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 433.8 243 Td(6) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 439.2 243 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 444.6 243 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 450 243 Td(2) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 455.4 243 Td(7) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 460.8 243 Td(,) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 466.2 243 Td(4) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 471.6 243 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 477 243 Td(5) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 482.4 243 Td(.) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 487.8 243 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 493.2 243 Td(8) Tj ET BT /F5 10 Tf 498.6 243 Td(-) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0 0.32 0.58 rg 0 0.32 0.58 RG BT /F5 26 Tf 60 512 Td(Your Investment Statement) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F5 10 Tf 60 497 Td(SEP 11, 2009 Through SEP 11, 2009) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG BT /F20 12 Tf 320 2 Td(Page 1 of 1) Tj ET 0.0 0.0 0.0 rg 0.0 0.0 0.0 RG
endstream
endobj
**6 0 obj**<< /Type /XObject /Subtype **/Name /Im1** /Image /Width 300 /Height 192 /ImageMask false /DeviceCMYK /Filter /RunLengthDecode /ColorSpace /BitsPerComponent 8 /Length 29396 >>stream
.
<JPEG Image Stream>
.
endstream
endobj
**41 0 obj**<< /ProcSet [/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] /**XObject << /Im1 6 0 R >>** >>endobj
7 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F1 /BaseFont /Courier /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
8 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F2 /BaseFont /Courier-Oblique /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
9 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F3 /BaseFont /Courier-Bold /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
10 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F4 /BaseFont /Courier-BoldOblique /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
11 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F5 /BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
12 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F6 /BaseFont /Helvetica-Oblique /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
13 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F7 /BaseFont /Helvetica-Bold /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
14 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F8 /BaseFont /Helvetica-BoldOblique /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
15 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F9 /BaseFont /Times-Roman /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
16 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F10 /BaseFont /Times-Italic /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
17 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F11 /BaseFont /Times-Bold /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
18 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F12 /BaseFont /Times-BoldItalic /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
19 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F13 /BaseFont /Symbol>>endobj
20 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F14 /BaseFont /ZapfDingbats>>endobj
.
<other Font Objects>
.
42 0 obj<</Producer(Version 2017A)/CreationDate(D:20180323114050)/ModDate(D:20180323114050)/Title(VPI Function EPM )/Creator(Version 2017A User: SMITH)/Author(Trust & Custody)>>endobj
xref
0 43
0000000000 65535 f
0000000166 00000 n
0000000229 00000 n
0000000273 00000 n
0000000329 00000 n
0000000735 00000 n
0000017926 00000 n
0000047618 00000 n
0000047738 00000 n
0000047866 00000 n
0000047991 00000 n
0000048124 00000 n
0000048247 00000 n
0000048378 00000 n
0000048506 00000 n
0000048641 00000 n
0000048766 00000 n
0000048893 00000 n
0000049018 00000 n
0000049149 00000 n
0000049242 00000 n
0000049341 00000 n
0000050416 00000 n
0000050612 00000 n
0000051687 00000 n
0000051883 00000 n
0000052958 00000 n
0000053154 00000 n
0000054229 00000 n
0000054425 00000 n
0000055496 00000 n
0000055688 00000 n
0000056761 00000 n
0000056959 00000 n
0000058036 00000 n
0000058253 00000 n
0000059325 00000 n
0000059526 00000 n
0000060605 00000 n
0000060830 00000 n
0000061897 00000 n
0000047529 00000 n
0000062095 00000 n
trailer << /Size 44 /Root 1 0 R /Info 42 0 R >>
startxref
62335
%%EOF
```

Comment: A bitmap image is either inline or a XObject resource, not both.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the `Page` and `ProcSet` objects isn't right. Currently:

```
% Current Page Object
4 0 obj <<
  /Type /Page
  /Contents 5 0 R
  /MediaBox [ 0 0 792 612 ]
  /Parent 3 0 R
  /Resources <<
    /Font <<
      /F1 7 0 R
      %% Etc...
    >>
    /ProcSet 41 0 R
  >>
>>
endobj
% ...
%% Current ProcSet object:
41 0 obj <<
    /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ]
    /XObject <<
        /Im1 6 0 R
    >>
>>
endobj
```

ProcSet should be a simple array and the XObject entry should be be back up a level in the Page resources dictionary. I'd suggest changing the structure to:

```
% Updated Page Object
4 0 obj <<
  /Type /Page
  /Contents 5 0 R
  /MediaBox [ 0 0 792 612 ]
  /Parent 3 0 R
  /Resources <<
    %% XObject Entry Moved here..
    XObject <<
        /Im1 6 0 R
    >>
    /Font <<
      /F1 7 0 R
      %% Etc...
    >>
    /ProcSet 41 0 R
  >>
>>
endobj
% ...
%% ProcSet changed to a simple array:
41 0 obj [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ]
endobj
```

Please see section 7.8.3 Resource Dictionaries of the [PDF 32000 Specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)

Comment: Thanks dwarring! Got syntax fixed. But once this was corrected, I'm getting Image Length issues. Is there a trick in determining or calculating the image length in the stream? I read image file record by record and write into pdf file stream and add up their lengths as if I'm calculating the length for any data file record length.

Comment: Stream Length is just the byte count of the stream in the PDF, which is the same as the length of the JPEG file. Maybe try with a small JPEG image and ask back on SO, if your stuck.